# Fitting curved lines to scatterplots in R

Tags: r, regression, scatterplot

I have created a scatterplot. I want to see the trend of how the number of fishing cat scats vary with an increase in perimeter of water body. Hence my response variable is `number of fishing cat scats` and predictor variable is `perimeter of water body`. After creating a scatterplot, I gave an `abline` (`lm`) command, which has given me a linear regression line, which doesn't exactly portray the relationship between `number of fishing cat scats` and `perimeter of water body`. What command do I need to use to generate a curve which fits the data?
I am using R as my statistical software.

Comment: The answers you got are fine;  just suggesting that this sort of question may get a lot more views in SO.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the `ggplot2` package. The command `geom_smooth()` will add a [loess](/questions/tagged/loess) line by default, which may result in [overfitting](/questions/tagged/overfitting). You can also plot a second- or third-order function using `stat_smooth(formula=y~scale(x)+I(scale(x)^2))` (modify this formula to suit your model). Example:

```
perimeter=rgamma(999,100);catscats=rpois(999,5);require(ggplot2)             #Simulated data
ggplot(data.frame(catscats,perimeter),aes(x=perimeter,y=catscats))+          #Call plot
stat_smooth(method='glm',family='poisson',formula=y~scale(x)+I(scale(x)^2))+ #Plot GLM line
geom_smooth(col='red',se=F)+geom_point()         #Plot LOESS line in red and add scatterplot
```

[image]

BTW, I fit a Poisson regression line here, but a negative binomial model might be wiser for your data depending on the dispersion of cat scats. You may prefer a confidence band around the LOESS line.

Comment: Thank you so much. My data is zero inflated count data.........so after running the command it says  "negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family"........what to do now?

Comment: Describe your new problem more specifically in a new question if you can't find another that already answers it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this, using the same data (except for random variation) that @Nick used

```
perimeter=rgamma(999,100);
catscats=rpois(999,5);
df <- cbind(perimeter,catscats)
plot(perimeter,catscats)
lines(lowess(df))
```